# Python3: Can't pickle DictReader instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, pickle

I have a file csvHelper.py where I read the csv and store it in a dictionary using
DictReader. But when I try to pickle this dictionary, I get the following error:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not the same object as _csv.reader

For reference, the relevant part of the code:

```
allData = DictReader(open('xyz.csv', 'rt'))

for row in allData:
    row["Element name"] = row["Element name"]+'##'

dataStore = open('myPickleFile', 'wb')
pickle.dump(allData, dataStore)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not pickling the dictioary, but `DictReader`.

If you want dump all dictionaries, gather them in a list, and dump the list:

```
import pickle
from csv import DictReader

with open('xyz.csv', 'rt') as f:
    allData = DictReader(f)

    rows = []
    for row in allData:
        row["Element name"] = row["Element name"]+'##'
        rows.append(row)

with open('myPickleFile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(rows, f)
```

Comment: I guess the intention was indeed to pickle `allData`, since `row` is a loop variable.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingl.

Answer (score 0):

`DictReader` is indeed unpicklable. Try converting `allData` to a list prior to processing:

```
allData = list(DictReader(open('xyz.csv', 'rt')))
```

This would also ensure that the changes you do to the individuals rows while iterating aren't lost.